# Hadoop: How to start 2 Mapper and 2 reducer

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, mapper

i'm trying to develop and Hadoop App. i want to start 2 Mapper and 2 Reducer in my main method. But the i keep getting a cast error, which bring me to ask how can i do this?

Mapper1:

```
@SuppressWarnings("javadoc")
public class IntervallMapper1 extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, LongWritable> {
    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(IntervallMapper1.class.getName());

    private static Category categoriy;
    private static Value value;

    private String[] values = new String[4];
    private final static LongWritable one = new LongWritable(1);

    @Override
    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        if(!this.categoriy.valueIsMissing(value.toString())){ // Luftdruck und Windstärke vorhanden...
            this.logger.info("Key: " + values[0] + values[1]);
            values = this.value.getValues(value.toString());
            context.write(new Text(values[0] + values[1]), this.one); // Station-Datum als Key und Value = 1
        }
    }
}
```

Reducer1:

```
@SuppressWarnings("javadoc")
public class IntervallReducer1 extends Reducer<Text, LongWritable, Text, LongWritable> {
    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(IntervallReducer1.class.getName());

    private String key = null;
    private static LongWritable result = new LongWritable();
    private long sum;

    @Override
    protected void reduce(Text key, Iterable<LongWritable> values, Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        for (LongWritable value : values) {
            if(this.key == null){
                logger.info("Erster Durchlauf");
                System.out.println("---> " + value.get());
                sum = value.get();
                this.key = key.toString().substring(0, 10);
            } else if (key.toString().contains(this.key)) { // TODO: key.toString().substring(0, 10)
                logger.info("Key bereit vorhanden");
                System.out.println("---> " + sum);
                sum += value.get();
            } else { // Falls Key nicht bereit vorhanden
                logger.info("Key nicht vorhanden");
                result.set(sum);
                logger.info("Value: " + sum);
                context.write(new Text(this.key), result);
                this.key = key.toString().substring(0, 10);
                sum = value.get();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Mapper2:

```
@SuppressWarnings("javadoc")
public class IntervallMapper1 extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, LongWritable> {
    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(IntervallMapper1.class.getName());

    private static Category categoriy;
    private static Value value;

    private String[] values = new String[4];
    private final static LongWritable one = new LongWritable(1);

    @Override
    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        if(!this.categoriy.valueIsMissing(value.toString())){ // Luftdruck und Windstärke vorhanden...
            this.logger.info("Key: " + values[0] + values[1]);
            values = this.value.getValues(value.toString());
            context.write(new Text(values[0] + values[1]), this.one); // Station-Datum als Key und Value = 1
        }
    }
}
```

Main:

```
@SuppressWarnings("javadoc")
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException, InterruptedException {
        Job job = Job.getInstance(new Configuration());

        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(LongWritable.class);

        job.setMapperClass(IntervallMapper1.class);
//      job.setCombinerClass(IntervallReducer1.class);
        job.setReducerClass(IntervallReducer1.class);
        job.setMapperClass(IntervallMapper2.class);

        job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
        job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);

        FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

        job.setJarByClass(IntervallStart.class);

        job.waitForCompletion(true);
    }
```

Error:

```
Error: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.io.Text
    at ncdcW03.IntervallMapper2.map(IntervallMapper2.java:1)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:146)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:787)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:164)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
```

Comment: I couldn't find IntervallMapper2 class??I think so you pased IntervallMapper1 twice instead of pasting IntervallMapper2

Comment: What do u mean exactly... i don't get it? parsed twice... How??

Comment: Let say i want to start 2 different Mappers and 2 different Reducers... How can i play the output from the 1. mapper into the input of the 1. Reducer and use the output of 1. Reducer as input of 2. Reducer?

Comment: in your exception you have mentioned IntervallMapper2 class. But in code above , so such class exist. Can you please correct the code you have provided

Comment: Looks like you pasted here the code of Mapper1 instead of code of Mapper2. There should be `IntervallMapper2` class instead of `IntervallMapper1` in Mapper2 section.

Comment: Hey... Can u tell me. How can i looking for some String using Hadoop-Map Reduce?